# "Too many arguments" error message in SUMPRODUCT

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

I'm somewhat newer at this, so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

I want to count each name I have listed in Column A once while ignoring blank spaces and excluding two different text values ("Total Providers" and "Providers") but I keep getting a "You've entered too many arguments for this function."

Here's the formula I'm using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A78<>"")/COUNTIFS(A2:A78&"",A2:A78,"<>Total Providers",A2:A78,"<>Provider"))
```

I'm definitely open to trying any other formulas. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you but I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: You have 5 criteria in the countifs.  the criteria in countifs should always be even.  you are missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You have 5 criteria in the countifs. the criteria in countifs should always be even. you are missing something. You also need to have all the same criteria in numerator:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A2:A78<>"Total Providers")*(A2:A78<>"Provider")*(A2:A78<>""))/(COUNTIFS(A2:A78,A2:A78,A2:A78,"<>",A2:A78,"<>Total Providers",A2:A78,"<>Provider")+(A2:A78="Total Providers")+(A2:A78="Provider")+(A2:A78="")))
```

Comment: I didn't know that the countifs criteria needed to be even - that makes so much sense. Thank you!